# Visual studio code and Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, visual-studio-code

I've installed VSC, on opening Meteor code all Meteor specific syntax is underlined in Green, I've also installed Typescript extension, but no use.

I've installed node, then I've installed tsd, then I've installed the meteor extension for tsd.

I can see the typings folder with a meteor subfolder [screenshot of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXrUZ.png), still the syntax is in green.

Can someone point me on how to enable VSC for Meteor development?

I want a solution for Windows.